# ERROR ITMS-90502 App Store Upload - Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, upload, app-store

Suddenly our project is not uploading properly to the App Store and we are stopped at this point :

[image: Error Image]

Error message:

> ERROR ITMS-90502: "Invalid Bundle. Apps that only contain the arm64 slice must also have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist."

We've tried all, this is our info.plist:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
<string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
<key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
<string>Optimio</string>
<key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
<string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
<key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
<string>6.0</string>
<key>CFBundleName</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
<key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
<string>APPL</string>
<key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
<string>1.0</string>
<key>CFBundleVersion</key>
<string>2</string>
<key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
<true/>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoadsInWebContent</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) upload your expense photos through camera and roll</string>
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>$(PRODUCT_NAME) upload your expense photos through camera and roll</string>
<key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
<string>Uploaders</string>
<key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
<string>Main</string>
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>arm64</string>
    <string>armv7</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
</array>
<key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
<array>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Also we have this build settings:

[image: Build Settings]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It may be a change in iTC that's causing it, but there does actually seem to be a fix.

I corrected the plists of ALL extensions in my (iOS11 only) project to include `arm64` as a requirement (`UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities`).

And then added this post install hook for cocoapods:
https://twitter.com/aaron_pearce/status/966530631608881153

Now uploaded successfully and going through processing.

EDIT:
Whilst this solution is valid, and worked perfectly well, it is no longer necessary. It seems that iTC has been "fixed", and now accepts (again) builds that have not had these changes made.
https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/296129

Comment: I don't know if it's a change to iTC that's causing it... The team that I work on is responsible for a companion tvOS and iOS app, and I deployed both fine yesterday morning, yet last night only the iOS app deployed, and the tvOS app ran into these issues. I've run the post-install hook and verified the keys were created in my pod plist and all of my frameworks plists as well, but am still failing iTC upload validation. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me. iTC was even giving errors on the upload of builds that had been previously submitted successfully.

Answer (score 7):

(I did try the post install hook as suggested [here](https://twitter.com/aaron_pearce/status/966530631608881153) but that didn't work)

Add the following xml to your main target's `info.plist` file,

```
  <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
  <array>
      <string>arm64</string>
  </array>
```

Then add the same xml to all your `info.plist` files in your pods project (if you have a pods project of course).

You should now be able to upload to iTunes connect.

Comment: The downvotes are probably collateral damage from quality problems in an earlier version of this answer.  See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/363986/a-valid-answer-deleted

Answer (score 1):

This looks to be a recent change that Apple made with ITC validation. Previously it was enough to flag your main project as restricted to `arm64`, but now it looks like you need to ensure that even embedded projects are flagged as well. Meaning that `Pods.proj` and any `Internal.proj` files need to be restricted along with the main project file.

Unfortunately right now Cocoapods, by default, builds frameworks that support arm64, armv7, and armv7s which causes an issue here. I was able to solve this problem by adding the following lines to my Podfile.

```
post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['VALID_ARCHS'] = 'arm64'
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Source:
https://gist.github.com/alexpersian/e6ab115dc12f3d48eee0e7f27dfb567d

Edit: (2/23/2018)
This issue looks to have been resolved on the iTC side based on the following forum thread. https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/296129